# SQL Server 2008 : assigning record set to variables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL Server 2008.
I need to be able to pass table output via stored procedure parameters.

Example: MyTable (col1, col2) has the following data:

```
1, 'A'
2, 'B'
3, 'C'
```

Stored procedure:

```
sp_read_tbl (@p1_col1 int     OUT,
             @p1_col2 char(1) OUT,
             @p2_col1 int     OUT,
             @p2_col2 char(1) OUT,
             @p3_col1 int     OUT,
             @p3_col2 char(1) OUT)
```

How can I do this inside a stored procedure?

Comment: That sounds like you're doing something strange. Could you just do insert into @table ... exec sp_read_tbl? and then just select the records in the procedure?

Comment: you're expecting all of those vars as outparams?  Why not just do a `select col1, col2 from yourDataSource order by col1`?  It seems like you're using enough out params to warrant the SP just selecting/returning the values yeah?

Answer (score 1):

As noted, this isn't the usual way you'd get data out of a table in a stored procedure.  And if your table ever gets a fourth row, you'll have to re-do not just the stored procedure, but also the code that calls it.

But if you really need to do this, you can. There are a number of approaches; mine would look like this:

```
-- DO NOT start your stored procs with "sp_".  That's reserved for MS.
-- Many people use "up_" as a substitute.  
create procedure dbo.up_read_tbl 
(  
         @p1_col1 int     OUT,
         @p1_col2 char(1) OUT,
         @p2_col1 int     OUT,
         @p2_col2 char(1) OUT,
         @p3_col1 int     OUT,
         @p3_col2 char(1) OUT
)
AS 
    SELECT top 1
           @p1_col1 = col1
       ,   @p1_col2 = col2
    FROM   dbo.MyTable

    SELECT top 1
           @p2_col1 = col1
       ,   @p2_col2 = col2
    FROM   dbo.MyTable
    WHERE  col1 <> @p1_col1

    SELECT top 1
           @p3_col1 = col1
       ,   @p3_col2 = col2
    FROM   dbo.MyTable
    WHERE  col1 <> @p1_col1
      AND  col1 <> @p2_col1
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer above.   Yes, a little strange, but it's a restriction of the calling app.  Is there any way to do this via cursor loop fetch?  Thank you.

Comment: @learningSQL Do you mean using the cursor inside the stored procedure?  You could, definitely, but if you have enough records in your table to make using a cursor more practical than what I did, you'd be talking dozens of output parameters.  Plus, you'd need a lengthy chunk of T-SQL code just to determine what parameters to update each iteration.

Comment: @learningSQL  Here's a thought, though: can your calling app handle XML?  You could return the entire table contents as XML in a single output parameter.  Then you could convert that XML to a DataTable or an XmlDocument or XDocument for further processing.

Comment: Hi, yes I meant using cursor inside stored procedure.  can you show me such code?  Calling app does not handle XML.  Thank you.

Comment: @learningSQL  May I ask why you want to use a cursor?  It will run more slowly and the code will be harder to understand if you use a cursor.

Comment: Hi Ann, was thinking it would be simpler.. but maybe not.  Table has 50 records, 4 columns to retrieve.  That's 200 parameters that I need to define in the Stored Procedure.  there's an identity column (Primary Key).

Comment: @learningSQL Would it be possible for you to pass in an input parameter for the primary key or for a record number?  Then you could use a simpler proc with fewer parameters. You'd just have to call it over and over.